# selecting SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) from specific columns of ListObject table

Tags: excel, range, visible, listobject, vba

I am trying to get only the visible cells of certain columns of a ListObject table into a range object.

This doesn't seem to work.

```
dim rng as range
with activesheet.listobjects("Tab_data").databodyrange
    set rng=.specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)
end with
```

but this works when i select entire range then offset 1st column to select the other 2 required columns!

```
dim rng as range
with activesheet.usedrange
    Set rng = .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count-1, .Columns.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
end with
```

but i cannot use the above in a formula as my formula is referring to only the 2 columns in the listobject shown below:

[image]

UDF Formula on worksheet:

```
=TagCloud(RngWrdLst as Range)
```

and i am using it as:

```
=TagCloud(tab_data[[Brands]:[Index]])
```

As you can see from the image, i only want the visible cell ranges from columns "Brands" & "Index" and not the cells from "COLUMN" column.

so the visible ranges i would like to have are:

```
"$B$2:$C$3,$B$45:$C$45,$B$75:$C$78"
```

### edit for @Jeeped :

If i have a UDF function being called from a worksheet cell and passed a ListObject range of columns B & C (only these columns and not entire databodyrange), then how am i going to find the RngWrdLst visible range?

e.g.

call from worksheet:

```
=TagCloud(tab_data[[Brands]:[Index]])
```

Function definition:

```
Function TagCloud(RngWrdLst As Range)
Dim VisibleRng As Range

With RngWrdLst
    Set VisibleRng = Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Union(.Columns(2), .Columns(3)))
    Debug.Print VisibleRng.Address(0, 0)
End With

'   do something with the visibleRng......
End Function
```

BTW, RngWrdLst would contain the 2 columns B & C. So how do i modify your code and get only the visible range from the function?

Comment: There are already native worksheet functions like [SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) and [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) that do this. What is your end-game?

Comment: @jeeped I am actually filtering the listobject using a listbox that is filled with the items from 1st column of the list object. End game is to use the visible words from 2nd column and their indices from 3rd column to create a tag cloud of words. The font size of words would depend on its  index. Font Color would be any chosen color gradient from light to dark (big to small).

Comment: @jeeped it seems listobject doesnt really hide the rows (especially the entire rows), hence the complete range address shows as visible address. Whereas, Activesheet.usedrange seems to take into account the entire rows as hidden, so it is able to give the visible range address.

Comment: i really need a workaround to get the visible range from the listobject columns ranges that are passed to the function. also, Subtotal and Aggregate are good for getting a count of visible rows, but they do not return a visible range object from a listobject.

Comment: Your first bit of code should work. Did you check what was returned for rng.Address in the immediate window?

Comment: which code were you referring? yes, it only shows the full range i.e. A1:C201 or B1:C201 etc.

Comment: see section "edit for @Jeeped :" in my original post...in simpler terms, i cannot send a range parameter to a User Defined function called from a worksheet cell, and finally get the visible range from that function. Pls note, the function will work, if i dont send any parameters in it, but it defeats my original purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) on a [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) of the columns you want.

```
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tab_data").DataBodyRange
    Set rng = Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
                        Union(.Columns(2), .Columns(3)))
    Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0)
End With
```

Alternately, shift right off the first column and resize one column less than the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) contains.

```
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tab_data").DataBodyRange
    With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0)
End With
```

Depending upon what you wnt to do with `rng`, you may have to loop through the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx).

Comment: cool. the 1st one works fine but the 2nd one only gives me the B column and not B and C. 

also my question is, i am calling the tagcloud function passing a listobject range called RngWrdLst to it. RngWrdLst consists of the B & C columns of the list. how do i find out the visible cells of this range in code?

Comment: 1) Sorry 'bout the second. I mistyped the column offset as a 0, not a 1. Amended above. 2) If you pass acrtoss `rng` that is all you have to do. It may have more than one area (see link above) but it has all of the cells.

Comment: the above still gives me only C column and not B & C. Also, my main query to implement your code will be if i have a function called from a cell being passed the B,C columns of the ListObject, then how do i find that range's visible cells?

Comment: a) Wow... I'm really not thinking today. When the range is offset, it is not longer necessary to intersect it. b) The code I write will return a range if written as a function.